# Open multiple URLs in separate Google Chrome browser windows

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome

I have a bunch of links that I need to open up on a daily basis on separate Google Chrome windows

The 7 links are listed within column A of the rawdata worksheet

I have been able to create this VBA code in Excel which opens up all of the links that I need under one Google Chrome window with each link opening up on its own separate tabs.

```
Sub openurl()
Dim ChromeLocation As String
Dim MyURL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Range("A1").Select
lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Set ws1 = Sheets("rawdata")
ChromeLocation = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" 'location of Chrome.exe in your PC
For i = 1 To lastRow
MyURL = ws1.Cells(i, 1)
    Shell (ChromeLocation & " -url -newtab " & MyURL)
Next i
End Sub
```

Is there a way that I could get the links to open up on separate Google Chrome windows instead of separate tabs? If so how do you go about doing that?

Thank you for your time and consideration regarding this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Only change this line

```
    Shell (ChromeLocation & " -new-window " & MyURL)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).